# Single-SignOn for multiple apps using MSA (AAD)

Tags: android, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-account

I am creating a new android app and I don't want users to again enter the credentials for my app. I want to use the already logged-in MSA account for logging-in to my app also. How can I do that? Does AAD/MSA supports single signOn for multiple apps within a mobile? How to configure that?

Comment: It should support it as long as the system browser is used for authentication. If you use a WebView within your apps, those have a separate cookie container and would not share SSO state.

Comment: You could refer to this article to [enable cross-app SSO on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-v1-enable-sso-android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow this article to [Enable cross-app SSO on Android using ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-v1-enable-sso-android).

Microsoft's identity platform, along with the SDKs, makes it easy to enable SSO within your own suite of apps, or with the broker capability and Authenticator applications, across the entire device.

The steps to follow are:

1.Enable broker mode in your application code's calling to the MS SDK.

```
AuthenticationSettings.Instance.setUseBroker(true);
```

2.Establish a new redirect URI and provide that to both the app and your app registration.

Your redirect URI must be in the proper form of:

```
msauth://packagename/Base64UrlencodedSignature
```

3.Setting up the correct permissions in the Android manifest.

In particular, these permissions are:

```
GET_ACCOUNTS
USE_CREDENTIALS
MANAGE_ACCOUNTS
```